# Where are TowerFall replays stored on OS X?

Tags: macos, towerfall-ascension

When I save a replay, TowerFall says that it's saved in my "Documents Folder". However, it is not in the User's `~/Documents` folder and I can't seem to locate it in any of the Steam support folders. It's probably somewhere in there, I just haven't stumbled on the right folder yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this post on the Towerfall steam forums](http://steamcommunity.com/app/251470/discussions/0/540743212975369309/), you can find the replays at `~/Library/Application Support/TowerFall/TowerFall Replays/`.